# Ordenar tres divs Horizontalmente

Tags: html, css, div

Necesito ayuda para alinear estos tres Divs Horizontalmente, intente recudir el tamaño de uno por si era porque no entraba pero fue en vano. Pienso que el container es pequeño, intente agrandarlo en el Style.css pero no funciono tampoco.

Este es mi index.html me faltaria agregar un header pero quiero solucionar este problema de estos divs

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .item {
  float: left;
}

.container .col-md-6 {
  float: left;
}

.container .col-md-3 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ChepesDeliveryManagerWeb</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-nNK9n28pDUDDgIiIqZ/MiyO3F4/9vsMtReZK39klb/MtkZI3/LtjSjlmyVPS3KdN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form id="task-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="task-title" class="form-control" class="Task Title" placeholder="Task Title" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea id="task-description" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Task Description"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-task-form">
                Save
              </button>

      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form id="task-frm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="ta-title" class="form-control" class="Task Title" placeholder="Task Title" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea id="tas-description" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Task Description"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-tak-form">
                Sav
              </button>

      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <form id="taskrm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="ta-tle" class="form-control" class="Task Title" placeholder="Task Title" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea id="tas-dription" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Task Description"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-form">
                Sav
              </button>

      </form>

    </div>



  </div>







  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyC9t7JmEgqONRgJ7KoZGzcb708C_rxlnqs",
      authDomain: "chepesdelivery.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://chepesdelivery-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "chepesdelivery",
      storageBucket: "chepesdelivery.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "541281515111",
      appId: "1:541281515111:web:1c8201aee43b70297d06c2",
      measurementId: "G-CZ5GLT4JQQ"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

En mi index.js no tengo nada aun

Bueno este es todo mi codigo. Tengo pensado integrar esta pagina con mi base de datos de Firebase y primero estoy desarrollando la interfaz, y me surgio este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar Flexbox;

```
.container {
border: solid red; /*Para que se vea el borde :)*/

display: flex;
flex-direction: column; /*Depende de lo que quieras usar, si una columna, o una hilera */
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Agregue todo eso al Style pero aun no se alinean los divs, pero con el borde rojo pude ver que el container no ocupa toda la pantalla, no se si tendra que ver

Comment: Actualización: Probe el Flexbox y logre alinear los tres en una sola linea, pero sobrepasa el borde de mi container. Pero no se como hacer para que mi conteiner ocupe todo el body

Comment: @LucasAndresEscudero Sí, hay una acción para evitar que eso pase.

Comment: Tienes que utilizar el siguiente código (puedes solamente copiar y pegarlo, solamente que tiene que estar dentro de la clase "container):

flex-wrap: wrap;

Comment: Y ya con eso no debería de sobrepasar el body. :D